# Etat HTTP 500 - "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat, web-applications

i wrote a simple programme in java as service web with eclips and apache-tomcat-8.0.32 server and axis2-1.7.0 
this is my code :

```
package services;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import simObject.control.Traitement_motion_sensor;
import simObject.sensor.Motion_sensor;
import listener_Thread.Motion_sensor_listener;
import grid.Position;
import grid.Grid;
public class SW_motion_senssor 
{
    public Traitement_motion_sensor traitement_motion_sensor;
    public Socket s;
    private int id_motion_sensor ;
    public Motion_sensor_listener ecout_mos;    
    private int motion_exist;
    private int port_motion_sensor;
    public Motion_sensor m;
    private int orientation;
    boolean running =true;
    public Grid g;
    public Position p;
    public SW_motion_senssor() throws IOException  
    {
        m=new Motion_sensor(p,g,porte);
    }
    }
        public int Get_existe()
    {
        return m.getMotion_exist();
    }
    public Position Get_position()
    {
        return m.getPosition();

    }

}`
```

when i executed it , the error below is occurred:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception

type Rapport d''exception

message "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception

description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l''a empêché de satisfaire la requête.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: "Servlet.init()" pour la servlet AxisServlet a généré une exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
cause mère

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
cause mère

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:61)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
    org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
    org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de Apache Tomcat/8.0.32.
```

Comment: The error is given in the log.. No Class Definition Found..

Comment: You are missing a _XmlSchema_ library from _Apache_, you can get it here  :  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.commons.schema/XmlSchema

Comment: @Berger: that's the wrong one; Axis2 1.7.0 uses Apache XmlSchema 2.2.1.

Answer (score 2):

for above comment continuation, place the xmlschema-core-2.2.1 in Tomcat lib or the server lib you are using... it worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

In Axis2 1.7.0 the Apache XmlSchema dependency was updated from 1.4.x to 2.x (which is a breaking change). Probably the Eclipse tooling hasn't been updated to take that into account and you still have XmlSchema 1.4.x (or the dependency is completely missing).

You need to add the following JAR to your application:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.apache.ws.xmlschema%20a%3Axmlschema-core

Comment: first i want to say thanks for everyone
secone i cheked the version of XlmSchema and it's 2.2.1 the latest

Comment: Probably XmlSchema is in the build path of the project, but not deployed to the server.

Comment: how can i deploy it to the server please ?

Answer (score 0):

These are the errors you are getting in your logs:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver`

You are missing XmlSchema jar from your environment. Please get this jar and try again.

Comment: thank u but i already have the latest version of XmlSchema 2.2.1
is there any other solution